# can I change value type in dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, types

can I change value type from string to float in dataframe

for example df

```
    a      b
0    0     0
1    1     1 
2    2     2
```

and df value type is string.

```
type (df['a'][0])  -> str
```

is there a way to change all value type from string to float?
should I use nested for loop? I tried to change as follows but it seems it's not the best way to change the type

```
for i in range(df(len)):
     df.loc['a',i] = float(df['a'][i])
     df.loc['b',i] = float(df['b'][i]) 
     i+=1..
```

Comment: I thin this post can give you more context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51817742/how-could-i-detect-subtypes-in-pandas-object-columns/51818821#51818821

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

`df = df.astype(float)`