# How could I detect subtypes in pandas object columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the next DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 3,4], 'b': [20.1, 2.3,45.3], 'c': [datetime.time(23,52), 30,1.00]})
```

and I would like to *detect **subtypes*** in columns without explicit programming a loop, if possible.

I am looking for the next output:

```
column a = [int]
column b = [float]
column c = [datetime.time, int, float]
```

Comment: col_a = [type(x) for x in a], where a is the value of the key 'a'. I don't know about pandas stuff. May be there is an easy way out.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41264303/9511702) could you help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should appreciate that with Pandas you can have 2 broad types of series:

1. Optimised structures: Usually numeric data, this includes `np.datetime64` and `bool`.
2. `object` dtype: Used for series with mixed types or types which cannot be held natively in a NumPy array. The series is structured as a sequence of pointers to arbitrary Python objects and is generally inefficient.

The reason for this preamble is you should only ever need to apply element-wise logic to the second type. Data in the first category is homogeneous by nature.

So you should separate your logic accordingly.

#### Regular dtypes

Use [`pd.DataFrame.dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html):

```
print(df.dtypes)

a      int64
b    float64
c     object
dtype: object
```

#### `object` dtype

Isolate these series via [`pd.DataFrame.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) and then use a dictionary comprehension:

```
obj_types = {col: set(map(type, df[col])) for col in df.select_dtypes(include=[object])}

print(obj_types)

{'c': {int, datetime.time, float}}
```

You will need to do a little more work to get the *exact* format you require, but the above should be your plan of attack.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use python built-in function [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map).

```
column_c = list(map(type,df['c']))
print(column_c)

output:
[datetime.time, int, float]

types = {i: set(map(type, df[i])) for i in df.columns} 
# this will return unique dtypes of all columns in a dict
```

Comment: This isn't really advisable. If you have an `int64` Pandas series with 1mio items, do you need to check the type of each one individually?

Comment: `column_c = list(map(type,df['c']))` is listing all the datatypes for all of the rows. Is there a way to list just the unique datatypes in column_c?

Comment: @NickT You can use `set(map(type, df['c']))`, do you note this checks datatype for each row.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to provide what I found to be a more readable version...

#### Load your packages and create the dataframe

```
# Packages
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# DataFrame  
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 3,4], 'b': [20.1, 2.3,45.3], 'c': [datetime.time(23,52), 30,1.00]})

# Map over each column individually, within a print
print("column a =", df.a.map(type).unique())
print("column b =", df.b.map(type).unique())
print("column c =", df.c.map(type).unique())

# Outputs:
column a = [<class 'int'>]
column b = [<class 'float'>]
column c = [<class 'datetime.time'> <class 'int'> <class 'float'>]
```

#### Likely unnecessary (and a bit more complicated), but would help you remove the `class` and `< >` characters is the following...###

```
# Use `.__name__` within a list comprehension to access only the type name
print("column a =", [x.__name__ for x in df.a.map(type).unique()])
print("column b =", [x.__name__ for x in df.b.map(type).unique()])
print("column c =", [x.__name__ for x in df.c.map(type).unique()])

# Outputs:
column a = ['int']
column b = ['float']
column c = ['time', 'int', 'float']
```

While this is repetitive, and I know that repetition in code is often frowned upon, it is much simpler to understand if you were sharing this code with someone else (at least to me) and, thus, more valuable (again in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

[@jpp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51818821/5472444) was helpful.

I expanded on it and wanted to show how the dtype to python type (`py_type`) related more explicitly, as wall as display the shorthand numpy kind, and tabulated as a metadata dataframe:

```py
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 3, 4], 'b': [20.1, 2.3, 45.3], 'c': [datetime.time(23, 52), 30, 1.00], 'd': ['s1', 's2', 's3']})

types_df = {
    c: {
        'dtype': df[c].dtype,
        'np_kind': df[c].dtype.kind if isinstance(df[c].dtype, np.dtype) else None,
        'py_types': set(map(type, df[c])) if df[c].dtype == np.dtype('O') else {df[c].dtype.type}
    }
    for c in df.columns
}

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(types_df, orient='index')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.applymap(type).apply(set)
```

If you only want to check columns with `dtype` of `object`, use:

```
df.select_dtypes(object).applymap(type).apply(set)
```

Your output will look something like:

```
column_a                                 {<class 'str'>}
column_b                {<class 'str'>, <class 'float'>}
column_c    {<class 'decimal.Decimal'>, <class 'float'>}
```

Explanation:

`applymap` will replace the value of each and every cell in the `df` with it's python `type`,

`apply` will then place all the values of each column into a python `set` object, which is like an array but duplicates are not allowed